# Changing amount of data shown per page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a rental website up, when you search for a item it displays 9 different items that users have posted, I call this with a **@foreach**, I want to change it to show 15. But I'm stumped on how to go about this, Any help?

Comment: Please show at least some code...

Comment: Into your Controller edit your `paginate()` method like this `->paginate(15)`

Comment: Read about pagination here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: if it is the other way around, I would definitely go with paginating, but how it is showing 9 and you want to show 15? is it a problem with your blade view? are you showing all the items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{  
    if(!$this->alreadyInstalled()) {
        return redirect('install');
    }

    $city_list = City::where('status','1')->orderBy('city_name')->get();

    $propertieslist = Properties::where('status','1')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(6)->get();

    $testimonials = Testimonials::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    $partners = Partners::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('pages.index',compact('propertieslist','testimonials','partners','city_list'));
}
```

Just realized that its in my Controllers, \app\Http\Controllers , and all I had to do was change the amount I wanted to take `->take(6)->`